# TortoiseProc Launch failed: The application has failed to start because its side-by-side configuration is incorrect

Tags: tortoisesvn, admin, elevated-privileges, windows-10

I installed Tortoise on Windows 10 (my user had admin privileges but installer wasn't ran as admin), and when trying to use any tortoise contextual menu, I was getting this error:

"TortoiseProc Launch failed: The application has failed to start because its side-by-side configuration is incorrect. Please see the application event log for more detail."

I verified, "run as Administrator" was *not* checked for TortoiseProc.exe file. I tried to check it, but this didn't change anything.

So I decided to uninstall it, and install it again. And then I was having this error:

- a dialog saying the TortoiseProc.exe requires elevation

Now, when attempting to run the app by double clicking on TortoiseProc.exe, I got a prompt saying this app required privilege admin. Clicking on OK ran it properly. So I guess the prompt isn't displayed when calling it from a contextual menu, and it silently fails.

I fixed the problem by right clicking on TortoiseProc.exe file -> proporties. Then, on the Compatibily tab, I clicked on "Run compatibility troubleshooter". And voila! It fixed the problem: TortoiseProc.exe now runs, and does not ask any admin rights!

Answer (score 0):

Run the [Command prompt (cmd.exe) with admin rights](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/How-do-I-run-an-application-once-with-a-full-administrator-access-token) and run this command:

```
SxsTrace Trace -logfile:SxsTrace.etl
```

Now run the Tortoise program which causes the SideBySide error.

Go back to the command prompt press ENTER to generate the SxsTrace.etl. Now type this:

```
sxstrace Parse -logfile:SxSTrace.etl -outfile:SxSTrace.txt
```

Now open the SxSTrace.txt trace and look which VC++ runtime is missing. Go to Microsoft.com, download and install the required version.

If you are unsure, please upload the complete SxSTrace.txt here.